# Whats the difference between a User and a UserModel

Tags: model, naming-conventions, naming

When would you append the name model to a class?
Is there a difference between them?

Does it depend on the architecture someone uses, let's say (MVC), and if so is there an underlying difference apart from the name?

Answer (score 1):

You would typically append the name *model* to a class which extends (is a subclass of) a model in a Model View Controller framework, e.g. *UserModel*. You may also have a *UserView* and a *UserController* which are subclasses of *View* and *Controller* respectively. It is common practice to add prefix words when you define a subclass to indicate the specialization.